# Neo4j Cypher MATCH and LIMIT, does limit work on match or on return only

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say i issue this query

```
MATCH(n:node)
RETURN n LIMIT 5
```

**Does cypher take into account the `LIMIT` clause when doing the matching?**

Tests on my data set would point towards the answer being no.
The above query takes 7366ms in the neo shell.
versus

```
MATCH (a:Address) where id(a) IN [1589346,1589347,1589348,1589349,1589350] 
RETURN a
```

which takes 81ms

I have also picked random ids so that they are not in the cache, with the same result for time.

Comment: You can add a `profile` statement in the beginning of a query and see what happens in each case.

Answer (score 3):

[UPDATED]

With your initial query, the `LIMIT` clause *should be* limiting the amount of work done by the `MATCH` clause. I verified this using `PROFILE` in neo4j versions 2.3, 3.0, and 3.1.1.

For example, in version 3.1.1, I created 20 nodes labeled `node`. Your query produced the following plan:

[image]

Notice that the number of DB hits by the `NodeByLabelScan` operation was only 6 (it is always 1 more than the `LIMIT` value in my tests), not 20 or 21.

This, however, does not mean that the `LIMIT` clause will always limit the amount of work done by the preceding `MATCH` clause. And, even if it did, the actual amount of work done by the `MATCH` clause can be much greater than implied by the `LIMIT` value.

For example, suppose the query were as follows (and also suppose there is no index for `:node(timestamp)`):

```
MATCH (n:node)
WHERE n.timestamp > 1234567890
RETURN n LIMIT 5
```

- If the total number of matching nodes in the DB was < 5, then the `MATCH` clause would have to scan *all* the `node` nodes.
- If the total number of matching nodes in the DB was >=5, then the `MATCH` clause would have to keep scanning *until* it found 5 matching `node` nodes. In the worst case, the 5th matching node may not be found until all the `node` nodes have been scanned.

Comment: Is there a way to limit the work done by MATCH if we just need random X number of nodes? IMO there should be. There are many cases where that would be useful.